# How to get the results of a Spring data elasticsearch query

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have made an elasticsearch query to find a page of members by county.

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface MemberSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Member, Long> {

    @Query("{\"match\": {\"county\": \"?0\"}}")
    Page<Member> findByCounty(String county);

}
```

The overall goal is to get all the memberId's returned from the query and to use them as a search criteria for another query. (The entity 'member' has a field called 'memberId')

I tried getting the page content (in order to get the memberId field from the page) using .getContent..

```
Page<Member> countyResults = memberSearchRepository.findByCounty(query);

System.out.println("county results: " + countyResults.getContent().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getMemberId)));
```

But I don't know what I'm really doing using .collect and it returns a bunch more than just the memberId

Here is what it shows in the sysout..

```
Member{id=1173, memberId='123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', ... }
```

I just need to get the memberId by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
for(int i=0; i<countyResults.getContent().toArray().length; i++) {
   System.out.println("key: " + countyResults.getContent().get(i).getMemberId());
}
```